# Using jquery to scroll down to #lower div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to use jquery to scroll down to the #lower div but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#lower").offset().top;
  }, 0); //end of animate 

}); //end of $(function()
```

```css
#upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#lower {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='upper'>Upper</div>
<div id='lower'>Lower</div>
```

Comment: Your DIVs are so small that there's no room to scroll down.

Comment: @Barmar Um, my divs have 100% width and height...

Comment: @Barmar It's stackoverflow that's making it seem so small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `;` : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` following `$("#lower").offset().top` ; adding `top` property to `#lower` greater than `window.innerHeight` to provide viewport distance between `#upper` , `#lower` elements

```js
$(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#lower").offset().top
  }, 0); //end of animate 

}); //end of $(function()
```

```css
#upper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#lower {
  top:300px;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id='upper'>Upper</div>
<div id='lower'>Lower</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to say scroll to a few pixels higher than #lower?

Comment: @jessica _"Is it possible to say scroll to a few pixels higher than #lower?"_  Yes. Try adding ` - n` following `$("#lower").offset().top` where `n` is a numeric value; e.g., `$("#lower").offset().top - 125`